# Using re and extract some patterns from list Python2.7

Tags: python, regex, list

I have such filenamelist from local directory.

> ['20150301',  '20150301121501.tar.gz',  '20150302', 
>   '20150302121501.tar.gz',  '20150303',  '20150303121501.tar.gz']

I wanna extract the yyyymmdd directory name,not tar.gzfile. this being ideal result.

> ['20150301', '20150302', '20150303']

I tried this one.

```
import re
pattern = "^(?!.*tar.gz).*$"
file_list = ['20150301',
 '20150301100.tar.gz',
 '20150302',
 '20150302100.tar.gz',
 '20150303',
 '20150303100.tar.gz']
matchOB = re.match(pattern , file_list)
```

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code with `^\d+$` regex matching a whole string that is composed of digits only:

```
import re

file_list = ['20150301',
 '20150301100.tar.gz',
 '20150302',
 '20150302100.tar.gz',
 '20150303',
 '20150303100.tar.gz']
matchOB = [x for x in file_list if re.search(r"^\d+$", x)]
print(matchOB)
```

[Sample online demo](https://ideone.com/MXLutw) output:

```
['20150301', '20150302', '20150303']
```

The `[x for x in file_list if re.search(r"^\d+$", x)]` list comprehension returns any element from the list that is only composed of 1+ digits.

If your date-like pattern always contains 8 digits, you may replace `^\d+$` pattern with `^\d{8}$`.

Comment: @strinbizhec thanks for sample program and explanation! Speeking greed,simply list is better ['20150301', '20150302', '20150303'] .

Comment: I am sorry, the answer was not quite OK as the lookahead was redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for items that don't have '.tar.gz' in their name.

```
for fyle in ['20150301', '20150301121501.tar.gz', '20150302', '20150302121501.tar.gz', '20150303', '20150303121501.tar.gz']:
    if '.tar.gz' not in fyle:
        print fyle
```

gives output:

```
20150301
20150302
20150303
```

---

To have the output as a list:

```
my_list = ['20150301', '20150301121501.tar.gz', '20150302', '20150302121501.tar.gz', '20150303', '20150303121501.tar.gz']
print [x for x in my_list if '.tar.gz' not in x]
```

has output:

```
['20150301', '20150302', '20150303']
```

Answer (score 0):

**By String processing:**

We can use `isdigit()` method of string and the `len()` function to validate string.

**Demo:**

```
>>> result = []
>>> input_dirs = ['20150301', '20150301121501.tar.gz', '20150302', '20150302121501.tar.gz', '20150303', '20150303121501.tar.gz']
>>> for i in input_dirs:
...   if i.isdigit() and len(i)==8:
...     result.append(i)
... 
>>> print result
['20150301', '20150302', '20150303']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression can work if you substitute last statement with

```
matchOB = [re.match(pattern, file).group() for file in file_list if re.match(pattern, file)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like that:

```
list = ['20150301', '20150301121501.tar.gz', '20150302', '20150302121501.tar.gz', '20150303', '20150303121501.tar.gz']
new_list=[]

for l in list:    
    if l.find(".")<0:       
        new_list.append(l)
```